# How do OneDrive's "smart files" work?

Tags: windows, onedrive

Since Windows 8.1, OneDrive uses "smart files" to represent files that exist in the cloud but are not available locally. How does this feature work? I can't find any documentation about it.

I can see that files that are not available offline have the following attributes:

```
Hidden, System, Archive, SparseFile, ReparsePoint, Offline
```

Also, using fsutil, I discovered that the reparse tag value is 0x80000015, which is not one of the `IO_REPARSE_TAG_*` values listed in WinNT.h. *(EDIT: actually it is: `IO_REPARSE_TAG_FILE_PLACEHOLDER`; I was looking at the WinNT.h from Windows 7 SDK, and this value is new in Windows 8.1)*

But that's about the only thing I could discover about them...

Is it possible to use this feature in my own app (i.e. provide my own smart files)? What APIs are available to manipulate those files?

Comment: This feature is [being removed in Windows 10](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/11/onedrive-getting-worse-to-get-better-in-windows-10/) as of build 9879... so I wouldn't bother investing in it. FWIW they're called "placeholders" and they're essentially symlinks.

Comment: @rikkit, given the ton of unanimously negative feedback [in the comments](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2014/11/12/new-build-available-to-the-windows-insider-program/) and [on UserVoice](https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6708195-add-an-advanced-option-to-restore-showing-all-oned), I wouldn't bet on this feature being removed... But anyway, I'm still interested in knowing how it works now.

Comment: Should say *as it is now* - the reason it's being removed from OneDrive is they're not happy with the current implementation. Though that won't affect any implementation you do. [This is the only documentation I could find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn323738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - though apparently [Symantec also use a version of this feature](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH145524)

Comment: DropBox apparently supports this down to Win7: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/04/dropboxs-project-infinite-shows-all-your-files-locally-without-using-any-disk-space/

Comment: @ddevienne, yes, I heard the news. But I don't think they're using the "placeholder" Windows feature, since it's only available since Windows 8.1. I wonder how they do it... probably a filesystem hook or something like that.

Comment: Old question but maybe the feature has been re-introduced;  a recent publication shows a demonstration of these files in use to build a [cloud-sync app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cfapi/build-a-cloud-file-sync-engine) which employs placeholders. However looking at [the code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CloudMirror) on github it seems there's a lot going on, and my c++ knowledge is too limited to provide much useful interpretation. Still, worth a look at - that's where your explanation lies...

Comment: @Greedo, that's useful, thanks!